# What does the about:dns page in Google Chrome show?

Tags: google-chrome

In the `about:dns` page in Google Chrome, does anyone know what these mean:

1. page load count
2. subresource navigations
3. subresource preconnects
4. subresource preresolves
5. expected connects (in decimals?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How many times the page has been loaded
2. How many times a link in that page was navigated to
3. Number of times the browser prefetched resources i believe
4. How many times the browser resolved the address of subresource
5. Number of HTTP connections (average?) browser needs to iterate to load the site's pages

Answer (score 2):

1. How many times the page has been loaded
2. How many times a link in that page was navigated to
3. Not sure
4. How many times the browser resolved the address of subresource
5. Not a clue, but I think its time based.